# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:-Quando abri o aplicativo dar erro ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, crud

toda vez que tento abrir uma consulta dar erro, estou utilizando php junto com java segue o erro abaixo:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar, PID: 11602
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar/br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar.alunos}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar.alunos.onCreate(alunos.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
```

meu codigo no VerAlunosAdapter.java é

```
    package br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class VerAlunosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<VerAlunos>lista;

    public VerAlunosAdapter(Context ctx2, List<VerAlunos> lista2){
        ctx = ctx2;
        lista = lista2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public VerAlunos getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista, null);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        VerAlunos c = getItem(position);

        TextView itemNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemNome);
        TextView itemIdade = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemIdade);
        TextView itemTelefone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemTelefone);
        TextView itemCelular = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemCelular);
        TextView itemTurma = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemTurma);
        TextView itemTurno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemTurno);
        //TextView itemProgress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemProgresso);

        itemNome.setText(c.getNome());
        itemIdade.setText(c.getTelefone());
        itemTelefone.setText(c.getTelefone());
        itemCelular.setText(c.getCelular());
        itemTurma.setText(c.getTurma());
        itemTurno.setText(c.getTurno());



        return v;
    }
}
```

o codigo em alunos.java é:

```
package br.com.alencardeveloper.escola.sisescolar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class alunos extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ListView listViewAlunos;

    private String HOST = "http://sis.colegioaplic.com.br/android";

    VerAlunosAdapter verAlunosAdapter;
    List<VerAlunos> lista;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        listViewAlunos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAlunos);

        lista = new ArrayList<VerAlunos>();
        verAlunosAdapter = new VerAlunosAdapter(alunos.this, lista);

        listViewAlunos.setAdapter(verAlunosAdapter);

        listaAlunos();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alunos);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tela_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_principal) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent abreTelaPrincipal = new Intent (this, TelaPrincipal.class);
            startActivity(abreTelaPrincipal);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_aluno) {
            Intent abreTelaAlun = new Intent (this, alunos.class);
            startActivity(abreTelaAlun);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notas) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    private void listaAlunos(){
        String url = HOST + "/alunos.php";

        Ion.with(getBaseContext())
                .load(url)
                .asJsonArray()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
                            JsonObject obj = result.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

                            VerAlunos c = new VerAlunos();

                            c.setId(obj.get("id").getAsInt());
                            c.setNome(obj.get("nome").getAsString());
                            c.setIdade(obj.get("idade").getAsString());
                            c.setTelefone(obj.get("telefone").getAsString());
                            c.setCelular(obj.get("celular").getAsString());
                            c.setTurma(obj.get("turma").getAsString());
                            c.setTurno(obj.get("turno").getAsString());
                            c.setMedia(obj.get("media").getAsString());

                            lista.add(c);
                        }
                        verAlunosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

a activity está abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_alunos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_tela_principal"
        app:menu="@menu/tela_principal_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Segue abaixo o app_bar_alunos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".alunos">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/listViewAlunos"
        layout="@layout/content_alunos" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

segue abaixo content_alunos.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".alunos"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_alunos">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewAlunos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Daniel!

Tente dessa forma

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alunos);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listViewAlunos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAlunos);

        lista = new ArrayList<VerAlunos>();
        verAlunosAdapter = new VerAlunosAdapter(alunos.this, lista);

        listViewAlunos.setAdapter(verAlunosAdapter);

        listaAlunos();


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Seu app dava crash devido uma `NullPointerException` que indica que você está tentando referenciar uma `View` que não existe no `layout` atual.

No seu caso, a `View` até existe, em tese, mas você tenta acessar ela antes mesmo do `layout` ser anexado à `Activity`. Esse método `setContentView(R.layout.alunos);` deve ser o primeiro a ser chamado, antes de qualquer referência à qualquer `View` dentro da `Activity`.

Após feito o procedimento acima, substitua esse include

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/listViewAlunos"
   layout="@layout/content_alunos" />
```

Por esse

```
<include layout="@layout/content_alunos" />
```

Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: tentei e não funcionou ainda, eu percebi está dando erro nesta linha listViewAlunos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAlunos);

Comment: Faça assim, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375483/edit) sua pergunta e inclua o `layout` da `Activity`

Comment: já editei Ivan.

Comment: Desculpa Daniel, inclua também `app_bar_alunos.xml`

Comment: Incluir também isto

Comment: Resumindo, a lista em está qual `layout`? É em `content_alunos.xml`?

Comment: Eu creio que deste alunos será o ultimo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92379/discussion-between-daniel-alencar-souza-and-ivan-silva).